# Most efficient way for generating simple JSON key value objects. Compile time strings?

Tags: c++, json, performance, optimization, printf

I'm currently communicating with my platform using a very simple JSON objects. For example, they follow the following format:

```
{"key":"value","key2":"value2"}
```

To avoid the overhead of various JSON libraries, I currently generate the JSON object with a simple sprintf statement:

```
sprintf("{\"key\":\"%s\",\"key\":\"%d\"}"), buffer, value, nValue);
```

This is great, because the buffer I generate is directly sent to the tcp socket and I don't have to convert from a JSON libraries type to a char*. The problem is that it's inconvenient to format the JSON, especially escaping the quotes. I'd like a more convenient syntax, while still allocating just a single buffer. An idea I had would be to create a wrapper function for this and generate the format string passed to sprintf at compile time. Resulting in a usage case similar to:

```
jsonHelperFunction(&buffer, key, value, key2, value2);
```

The helper function would probably have to use templates, but I'm unsure how to use them in a way to generate the format string to be used by sprintf. Does anyone know how to do this efficiently at compile time?

Comment: I would create a few simple classes representing the handful of JSON types: a value, a map, etc... Simple methods, for compound objects (like map), to add child values. Then a "format" method to recursively format everything into a `std::ostream`. Then, the whole thing can simply be instantiated in `auto` scope (on the stack), then formatted into a `std::ostringstream`, producing a `std::string` that can be written out. No heap allocation. No worrying about buffer overflow from a crude C-style `sprintf()` approach.

Comment: "To avoid the overhead of various JSON libraries" usually means "I'm reinventing the wheel, and corner cases are going to bite me in the ass". Seriously, use a real JSON serializer, don't try reinventing it yourself. The moment one of your values contains a double quote character, you're going to explode.

Comment: Side-note: If you're annoyed by all the backslash escaping, you might want to look at [C++11 raw string literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#New_string_literals) that allow you to use arbitrarily complex delimiters such that you never need to use escapes in a string.

Comment: Why use sprintf? Make your helper function use ostringstream instead and you don't need to generate a format string.